# CPU Frequency in AVR, CodeBlocks and Proteus

Tags: codeblocks, avr, atmega

Well, I'm using Code::Blocks as the IDE, and Win AVR as the compiler.
F_CPU is selected as 8000000UL.
I'm writing code for Atmega32.
But when I run my written code (*.hex file) in Proteus design suite (ISIS) the *_delay_ms(1000)* doesn't give a delay for 1sec. I don't know if it is write or wrong, I've selected *CKSEL fuses* to be *(0100) Int.RC 8MHz* in edit component.
What's wrong?
please....

Comment: The internal RC oscillator's frequency is not exact. If you want a precise delay, use an external quartz crystal oscillator.

Comment: It's a computer simulation. Well, I'm not opting for exact 1sec delay. But, the delay func. executes in a blink.

Comment: Also don't expect a simulator to work properly. It won't. Try on the actual device. Then it will.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the compiler optimization to something other than -O0? From the [avr-libc docs](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__delay.html) regarding *delay** functions.

> In order for these functions to work as intended, compiler
>   optimizations must be enabled, and the delay time must be an
>   expression that is a known constant at compile-time.

Comment: Actually, the problem was the winavr compiler. I reinstalled it and now it is working.

Answer (score 2):

Using PWM for servo control I figured out that even with this setting of Internal 8Mhz, Proteus are actually simulated with a clock of 1Mhz. If you change `F_CPU` to `1000000UL` you will see that delay will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Its just proteus simulation lags. On the real device your delay function will work properly. In order to simulate time delays the good choice is using avr studio program.